# Cosmos DB Table API with .NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I can see documentation on how to use Cosmos DB Table API with .NET here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet.

But I can't make this work with .NET Core project. Is there a way to make a working call to Cosmos DB Table API for .NET Core?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) Which nuget package you're using? 2) What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Based on my test, we also could use [WindowsAzure.Storage (9.1.1)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/9.1.1) to operate Cosmos DB Table API, it  could be used for .Net Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no .NET Core version of the Cosmos DB Table API, but they are working on it. See the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/344.

From [one of the comments](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/344#issuecomment-405804017) there:

> We are fully committed to delivering a .Net Standard SDK for Table API. We are tracking for delivery by October or before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following nuget package to the dotnet core project

**`dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`**

I have written a blog on  [Wear out the features of Azure CosmosDB with AspNetCore application](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2018/03/wear-out-features-of-azure-cosmosdb.html)

**EDIT**

Click Install to install the [**`Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet) library. This installs the Azure Cosmos DB Table API package and all dependencies.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. For the Cosmos DB SQL API (Document) it works totally fine and Microsoft also has a documentation for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnetcore-get-started. I am asking for the Cosmos DB Table API

Comment: @muhihsan You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a .net core API for the table storage features of cosmos. You can use the DocumentDb.Core lib, but nothing that will allow you to work with tables in the same way that you can with table storage. How rubbish is that?!

Comment: Is there any Cosmos DB support for .NET Standard?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to develop .NET Standard applications for Azure Cosmos DB Table API, you should install the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table package

You can check out the NuGet specs here:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table